# XCode crashes everytime I try to run project

Tags: xcode, macos, crash

Ever since I upgraded to XCode 5, I havent been able to run a project. Every time I hit the play button, XCode immediately freezes, and then crashes a few seconds later. If I press Command+B to build the project, it succeeds, its just running it that causes issues. This is on both iOS and OSX projects.

Here is the crash log it presents after the program closes: https://gist.github.com/EthanArbuckle/7406894

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? Its driving me crazy!

Comment: Have you tried turning it on and off again...No but seriously have you  tried reinstalling it? I had a similar issue when Xcode 4 came out and a reinstall fixed it.

Comment: Yep, multiple reinstalls

Comment: Same issue! I've even started calling it "The crash button"

Comment: Having this same problem--no fix, but a workaround:  If I hover on the lower-right of the play button then click-hold on the down arrow, then select 'Run' from the drop-down menu, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns` and remove the following directory (take the backup first) `IDERepositoryViewer.ideplugin`. Quit and relaunch the XCode and it should work fine.

Comment: That file doesnt exist